# Routing static assets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to have a folder structure to organize the assets I would like to serve that I don't want reflected in the urls I have. For example, I have

- assets
- - css
- - - bootstrap
- - - less_generated
- - - general
- - js
- - - bootstrap
- - - coffee_script_generated
- - - typescript_generated
- - - general

The folder structure is a concern for me, as the developer, but not for the resource address. I would like /assets/filename.css to look for filename.css in any of the listed folders that may contain css files, and serve the first one found. And do the equivalent for .js files.

I can't find a way to route this in MVC. All routes route to a controller, and I'd like to route to a file resource instead, and writing a controller to serve static resources seems just wrong, especially with all the behaviour surrounding cache control headers that I then would have to do manually. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you serving these files to callers outside the site, like an API? If not; if those files are only used internally in your website, why does the url format matter? Just curious as to your use case.

Comment: @JasonEvans im converting some of my css to less. I want the generated css to be in a separate folder to easily see where the css is coming from: is it hand written? Then you can freely edit it without it being overwritten by less. Is it generated, then you should edit the less file instead. But I don't want to go searching through all views to find all references to the file. I forsee the same thing happening with images that may be pre-scaled or sprited, and js files that may come from various pre-processors, which means I would also have to check all js that may request the resource

Comment: You could try using Bundles for this or a 404 handlers or a http module